# Problems with booting (black screen) on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: boot

I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, without dual boot.

I am using Ryzen 5 7500F, Gigabyte B650M-K, and GTX 1060 3GB.

The problem I am having is that when I turn on my PC, I won't be seeing any screens but only a black screen (without white underscore or any letters) once I boot it up. I can't even see the BIOS screen(the one with the manufacturer logo) and have no access to BIOS and GRUB while it boots up. (One thing to notice is that my RGB on my mouse is turned on, but then turned off, and turned on again.) But while there is only black screen while startup, it does boot properly to the login screen, and works perfectly fine after the PC is booted up. Also, this only happens when I boot the PC, and this won't happen if I was restarting my computer, GRUB shows up when I restart my computer.
I think it might be a problem with Nvidia because I am using GTX1060 3GB for my graphics card. I tried switching different versions of Nvidia drivers and switching the kernels, but I wasn't able to make any difference.

Would there be anything else for me to try?